# Почему спрайт в unity не перекрывает обьект?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Ситуация следующая. Я делаю 2д игру, там некий генератор генерирует шарики. Ставлю на сцену какой нибудь спрайт, ну например дерево. Так вот я его переношу перед бэкграундом, т.е. дерево закрывет бэкграунд. Дерево также должно закрывать сгенерированный (в будущем) шарик, но как не старайся, оно его не закрывает. Вот что интересно , если взять какой нибудь 3д обьект, например куб и закрыть им сгенерированный шарик то он его перекроет, но спрайт на том же месте куба его не перекрывает. Почему так? Как это исправить ? Вот дополняю вопрос картинкой может так понятней:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот еще картинка - это та же сцена в 3д:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Только сгенерированные шарики не перекрываются и не перекрываются они спрайтом а вот 3 д обьектом типа куб они перекрываються, почему?

Comment: "Я как-то генерирую **какие-то** шарики..." - что за объекты? Какая у них z координата, какой слой, дополните вопрос, пожалуйста.

Comment: Слоев там нету я менял координату z, но так почему то не работает.

Comment: А у дерева какая z координата?

Comment: Ну координата дерева -7.57, координата куба -5.09, координаты шариков почему то разные -8 , 1.8, -7, 1,8 короче рандомные, хотя если перекл в 3д, то вроде в 1 плоскости стоят. Скрипт не мой, я там все не понял.

Comment: Из ваших слов складывается впечатление, что проблема в координате z. Если вы хотите чтобы дерево было поверх шариков. Координата Z должна быть больше, чем у шариков.

Comment: А как вам помочь, если у вас "короче рандомно" генерируется z-координата, и вы при этом не приложили код?

Comment: В Unity нет разделения на 2д и 3д, все и всегда происходит в 3д.

Comment: Просишь прикрепить код - получаешь ненужный скриншот -_-

Comment: Да я просто не знаю что там крепить,скрипт большой. Я просто не пойму как такое возможно видно же, что куб перекрывает шарики а дерево перекрывает куб. Почему тогда шарики вылазят поверх дерева ?

Comment: Слои, например, кастомный порядок отрисовки в шейдерах, вариантов много и тыкать пальцем в небо я не хочу. Z-координата далеко не всегда влияет на порядок отрисовки.

Comment: Кстати скриншот объекта-дерева тоже не помешал бы.

Comment: Так вроде  все заскринил. Дерево - куб - шарики. Слои наверно надо мне почитать но там слой default Там любой спрайт не перекрывает шарики.

Comment: Все я нашел причину, позже напишу ответ действительно причина была в слоях, там у спрайта слой был 0, а у сгенерированных шариках разные рандомные но не 0. Ну думаю новичкам будет полезно не зря писал :)

Answer (score 1):

Причина была в том что генератор шариков генерировал шарики и ставил им Sorting Layer +1.
А в спрайтах у меня стоял Spriting Layer 0, я поменял его на -1 и шарики начали ехать по спрайтам. Чтобы спрайты перекрывали шарики я поставил Sprite Layer 1000000 (сколько шариков скрип не сгенерирует)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]